# show nearest distance within 1 km of current location from a list of given coordinates in a List view

Tags: latitude-longitude, android-studio-3.0, google-latitude

I have a list of Hospitals with their latitude & longitude. On button click it should populate the hospitals in 1km distance from my current location.

Comment: Create [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), describe your issues, use proper tags, don't post additional info in comments - you can [edit] your question

Comment: @Ankit, show us what you did earlier and where you got stuck. thank you